# ELB can't proxy traffic to my EC2 instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

For some reason ELB isn't correctly forwarding requests to my instance on EC2.

My setup is simply a `micro` instance with `nginx`/`node`, listening on ports `80` and `443`. The instance gets the health checker requests through ELB perfectly.

> 10.185.1.190 - - [01/Oct/2013:15:26:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 40 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
>
> 10.185.1.190 - - [01/Oct/2013:15:26:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 40 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
>
> 10.185.1.190 - - [01/Oct/2013:15:27:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 40 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
>
> 10.185.1.190 - - [01/Oct/2013:15:27:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 40 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
>
> 10.185.1.190 - - [01/Oct/2013:15:28:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 40 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
>
> 10.185.1.190 - - [01/Oct/2013:15:28:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 40 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
>
> 10.185.1.190 - - [01/Oct/2013:15:29:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 40 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
>
> 10.185.1.190 - - [01/Oct/2013:15:29:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 40 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
>
> 10.185.1.190 - - [01/Oct/2013:15:30:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 40 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"

However, requesting it through the browser directly doesn't work at all.

It should be noted that my instance *is accessible directly*, through its IP. The SG is configured to allow any connections on both ports, and ELB just proxies them to the instance.

ELB reports the instance is `Out of Service`.

Health Check:

```
Ping Target: HTTP:80/
Timeout: 5 seconds
Interval: 30 seconds
Unhealthy Threshold: 2
Healthy Threshold: 10
```

Neither HTTP nor HTTPS work on ELB, and both work on the instance.

Obviously, in my `nginx` logs I don't get anything when trying to request an ELB instance. `curl` reports:

> HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity

Halp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is returning a 302 (redirect) response code, and ELB looks for a 200 response code to consider an instance in service.  You need to have healthcheck look at a page that doesn't redirect.